# Tomcat Eclipse ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: eclipse, ssl, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, osx-elcapitan

I configured Tomcat 7 for SSL. I generate the keystore like this

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

in the server.xml, i have

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tomcat" keystoreFile="/Users/xxxxx/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" />
```

If I run tomcat directly, $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh, when I access https://localhost:8443 from Chrome, at least i got the warning of untrusted certificate, etc...

However, if I start Tomcat from Eclipse, it keep getting this error

```
localhost uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I even added the ciphers to the Connector, but still same error

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tim" keystoreFile="/Users/z0029mb/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" 
               ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"/>
```

JAVA_HOME is jdk1.8.0_101, for both Eclipse and Tomcat, running on OS X. So why does Eclipse Tomcat plugin interfere anything with Tomcat starting up that make Tomcat behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SHA-1 hash function, you might have to re-key the certificate from your Certificate Authority (CA) to use SHA-2. This is because SHA-1 is potentially unsecure.

1) Generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request)
2) Submit CSR to your CA
3) After your CA issues the certificate files, download and install them based on your server type and CA's instructions.